# I want to detect what event was triggered from a plugin

Tags: jquery

I made a plugin, and I need to detect what event was triggered. I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
if($(this)(which event fired) == "submit");
```

The plugin is called like this => `$("selector").track();`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should listen to events individually I believe.

Comment: does your plugin have an event called submit ?

Comment: submit: function(){code here}its called on the page in a submit call

Comment: Maybe post your plugin's implementation so we can answer properly.

Comment: _gaq.push(['_set', 'hitCallback', function(){
       var test = (typeof url === "undefined")? url="":window.location.href=url;
       DimitriLogEvent(cat.toLowerCase(), settings.windowType +" - " + action.toLowerCase());
      }]);
      return _gaq.push([settings.method, cat.toLowerCase(), settings.windowType.toLowerCase() + " - " + action.toLowerCase()]);

Comment: i need to know which event was fired to know which google tracking to fire in the callback. i need to know to submit form or to send it to the href of an a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### test it against the action and href attributes instead

Comment: Please explain your answer and how you arrived at it with background info.